# App Script - Trigger setting does not work properly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have a project in which I would like to use the onFormSubmit trigger, but I can't set it because I keep getting a message: "Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.". On another account I can set such a trigger without any problem, but I want it to work correctly on another account too. What can cause such an error? Is it possible for one account to have the restriction and the other not?

Comment: Are you using the onformsubmit for the spreadsheet or the form?

Comment: @Cooper, From one account I am unable to create any kind of trigger (for example onEdit does not work either). I always get the same error message that I described above. I tried to create the trigger manually and the result was the same.

Comment: I would check with google support